# Command line interface with multiple commands using click: add unspecified options for command as dictionary

Tags: python, python-click

I have a command line interface build with click which implements multiple commands.

Now I want to pass unspecified named options into one command which is here named `command1` e.g. the number of options and their names should be able to vary flexibly.

```
import click


@click.group(chain=True)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, **kwargs):
    return True


@cli.command()
@click.option('--command1-option1', type=str)
@click.option('--command1-option2', type=str)
@click.pass_context
def command1(ctx, **kwargs):
    """Add command1."""
    ctx.obj['command1_args'] = {}
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        ctx.obj['command1_args'][k] = v
    return True


@cli.command()
@click.argument('command2-argument1', type=str)
@click.pass_context
def command2(ctx, **kwargs):
    """Add command2."""
    print(ctx.obj)
    print(kwargs)
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli(obj={})
```

I have already looked into [forwarding unknown options](http://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/advanced/#forwarding-unknown-options) like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944131/add-unspecified-options-to-cli-command-using-python-click) but the problem is that I have to call (chanin) other commands after the first one which have to be asserted e.g. this call has to work but with arbitrary options for `command1`:

```
$python cli.py command1 --command1-option1 foo --command1-option2 bar command2 'hello'
```

So how can I add unspecified named options to a single command and call (chain) another one at the same time (after it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom class found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50883904/7311767), can be adapted to your case.

#### Using the Custom Class:

To use the custom class, just use the cls parameter to the click.command() decorator like:

```
@cli.command(cls=AcceptAllCommand)
@click.pass_context
def command1(ctx, **kwargs):
    """Add command1."""
    ...
```

#### Test Code:

```
import click

class AcceptAllCommand(click.Command):

    def make_parser(self, ctx):
        """Hook 'make_parser' and allow the opt dict to find any option"""
        parser = super(AcceptAllCommand, self).make_parser(ctx)
        command = self

        class AcceptAllDict(dict):

            def __contains__(self, item):
                """If the parser does no know this option, add it"""

                if not super(AcceptAllDict, self).__contains__(item):
                    # create an option name
                    name = item.lstrip('-')

                    # add the option to our command
                    click.option(item)(command)

                    # get the option instance from the command
                    option = command.params[-1]

                    # add the option instance to the parser
                    parser.add_option(
                        [item], name.replace('-', '_'), obj=option)
                return True

        # set the parser options to our dict
        parser._short_opt = AcceptAllDict(parser._short_opt)
        parser._long_opt = AcceptAllDict(parser._long_opt)

        return parser


@click.group(chain=True)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, **kwargs):
    """"""


@cli.command(cls=AcceptAllCommand)
@click.pass_context
def command1(ctx, **kwargs):
    """Add command1."""
    ctx.obj['command1_args'] = {}
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        ctx.obj['command1_args'][k] = v


@cli.command()
@click.argument('command2-argument1', type=str)
@click.pass_context
def command2(ctx, **kwargs):
    """Add command2."""
    print(ctx.obj)
    print(kwargs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        "command1 --cmd1-opt1 foo --cmd1-opt2 bar command2 hello",
        '--help',
    )

    import sys, time

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cli(cmd.split(), obj={})

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> command1 --cmd1-opt1 foo --cmd1-opt2 bar command2 hello
{'command1_args': {'cmd1_opt1': 'foo', 'cmd1_opt2': 'bar'}}
{'command2_argument1': 'hello'}
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND1 [ARGS]... [COMMAND2 [ARGS]...]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  command1  Add command1.
  command2  Add command2.
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!